# Data within modal not reflecting the data being passed

Tags: react-native

I am hoping someone can point what I am misunderstanding. I have placed `console.log` around the code but feel like I am missing something important. The way it is done is:

1 - Grab a collection of items

2 - Pass items data down to the model that support to open

3 - When open model it should show that specific item click info

PROBLEM: I am seeing the same data for every modal I keep clicking to open. Is there a reason why the data seems to be the same even though I am iterating using a `FlatList`

```
  <FlatList<any>
    numColumns={2}
    contentContainerStyle={{
      alignItems: "center",
    }}
    data={items}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={renderImages}
  />

return (
  <View key={item.id}>
    <MiniProfileModal
      id={item.id}
      url={item.imageURL}
      userName={item.title}
      showModal={showModal}
      setShowModal={setShowModal}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Can you show us the `showModal` function, MiniProfileModal, and renderImages?

Comment: @Steven Ossorio check new solution

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, Modals are not rendered on the same component tree as other components. This has more benefits as modal can overlay other components and state changes in other components will not affect modal rerender which improves performance.

To solve this problem, you need to force the modal to rerender when new items are selected to keep up with those changes.